# PHP download files from server doesn´t work through ajax request

Tags: php, ajax

I have a PHP script which downloads a file from the server and works fine when it is called from an href tag, but it doesn't work if the same PHP script is called from an ajax request. (I need to use the ajax request instead because I need to extract the path of the file from a MySQL db prior to download the file)
I'd really appreciate any help with this.

PHP (mydownload.php)

```
<?php
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.pdf");
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
readfile("myfile.pdf");
?>

HTML (index.html)
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function miFuncion()
{
  $.ajax({
    url: "mydownload.php",
    type: "post",
    success: function(res){
    }
  })
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

  <a href="mydownload.php">Download the document (PDF)</a> // Work !

  <form>
     <input type="button" onclick="miFuncion()" value="Activar Función DL"> // Doesn`t work
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

As I said before, using the option from the href tag, the file is downloaded without any problem, but using the option from ajax request I get the following screen instead:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gr4oD.png)

Comment: If you're using Ajax to download files, then you're telling the browser that you're going to handle everything to do with the response yourself within your javascript, with the code inside `success: function(res){
    }`.... why not simply use a link, which tells the browser that it should handle the response

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your answer, problem is that the user can select which file to download. so I need to pass the name of that file to the script. I don`t know how to pass parameters to php script without ajax.

Answer (score -1):

You should generate an url to pass through your ajax request (like in json), and then you can do something like `location.href = your_download_url;`
In your case, you are not generating files dinamically, so you can call directly `location.href = "/download.php";` in `miFuncion()` without ajax request.